# Existing Java exception for when adding to a collection would exceed fixed size?

Tags: java, exception, collections

Is there an existing Java exception that can be thrown when an attempt is made to add an item to a fixed-size custom collection, where the operation would cause the collection to exceed its size?  The collection is a form of queue, so the concept of "index" isn't exposed by its interface, otherwise I'd use IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayBlockingQueue` in the JDK already has this use case, and it throws `IllegalStateException` in the case where the collection is already full.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#add(E)

> Throws:
>   IllegalStateException - if this queue is full

So `IllegalStateException` is the exception Java already uses in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could also throw an `IllegalArgumentException` simply because, as the docs state, it is...

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

which would also be technically correct given the collection and method is well documented. It would then be assumed to be the client's responsibility to check capacity before inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually throw IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
 throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("your message goes here");
```